# CakePHP 2.1 How to generate code for a single view?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-bake

I found that the explanations in 
[the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) do not match my own experiences with the bake shell.

When I run `./cake bake` from the shell, I don't get the output as specified above, instead it asks me for an app path and a skeleton path, and then wants to bake a whole application.

I have written most of my code and would like to just bake a single view, i.e. a form for this view. I would like to have the interactive shell like I knew it from 1.3 but I might be doing something wrong.

Like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /path-to/project/app
---------------------------------------------------------------
Interactive Bake Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
[D]atabase Configuration
[M]odel
[V]iew
[C]ontroller
[P]roject
[F]ixture
[T]est case
[Q]uit
What would you like to Bake? (D/M/V/C/P/F/T/Q)
>
```

**Edit:**

Here is the output when I just run `./cake`

```
Current Paths:

-app: Console
-working: /home/username/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/aurinko/aurinko/app/Console
-root: /home/username/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/aurinko/aurinko/app
-core: /home/username/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/aurinko/aurinko/lib
```

My working app lies in the path specified as root. What do I need to set app to, in order to just generate single views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I did not try enough. With this command it worked:

```
./cake bake -app /home/username/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/aurinko/aurinko/app/
```

Now the interactive shell appears as known from 1.3.

Maybe this helps somebody.